# subversion 1.6 file svn:externals help

Tags: subversion, version-control

Can someone please point out how I could do svn:externals for a single file?
I know how to use svn:externals for directories, having used it for a while now under svn 1.4 but I can't seem to figure out how to do file externals in 1.6.

I can't also figure out the documentation in the svn redbook here http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.externals.html.

Thank you so much in advance.

Ismael :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You include the relative path to the imported copy of the file followed by the absolute path to the external copy of the file on the same line in the svn:externals property of a parent folder to the imported copy.  The external file must be in the same repository an it's imported copy.  Use svn propedit svn:externals . and add a line like:

> path/to/imported/file.txt
>   http://www.example.org/svn-repo/external/file.txt

Just make sure it's in the same repository.  Also read:

http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.6.html#file-externals